# \TeX in small caps?

Tags: macros, small-caps

I'm writing a handout for an informal LaTeX course I'm running. I want to use small caps to highlight important words concepts etc. I mention the editor TeXshop, and since I think the names of editors are important, I put it in small caps:

```
\textsc{\TeX shop}
```

This doesn't work, since the `\TeX` macro ignores the small caps, basically. So I tried scaling it myself.

```
\textsc{\scalebox{0.8}{\TeX} shop}
```

But this doesn't work because extra space opens up between the `\TeX` and the `shop`. So I try to get rid of that space:

```
\textsc{\scalebox{0.8}{\TeX}\hspace{-0.4em} shop}
```

Which looks almost right. But not quite. So instead of messing around with tweaking the parameters, I was wondering if there was a better way to do this. I tried looking up the macro in `texdoc source2e` but my pdf reader's find function isn't case-sensitive, and searching the LaTeX source code for `\tex` is not helpful...

Comment: I believe the small-caps is ignored because the `\TeX` macro contains only uppercase letters. There is no difference, as typesetting `\TeX\textsc{shop}` versus `\scTeX\textsc{shop}` with `\newcommand\scTeX{\textsc{T}\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {\textsc{E}}\kern -.125em\textsc{X}}` suggests.

Comment: I assume that you don't feel `\textsc{TeXshop}` is acceptable? I'm not alone in preferring 'TeX' to '\TeX' in running text, I think!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Somehow this is a non-answer, but I'd suggest to stick with `\textsc{\TeX shop}`. What is the idea of small caps, after all? They use the usual capital letter, and only for *small letters* it's "small capital letters", in short "small caps". And the letters in `\TeX` are all capital from the start, so nothing should change there.

If you really want everything in small caps, then you easily find the definition of `\TeX` by `\show\TeX`; the result is essentially shown in Pieter's comment to the question. Some fiddling with the spacing yielded

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\textsc{t\kern -.12em\lower.4ex\hbox{e}\kern-.1em xshop}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Seamus,

I thought this was an interesting (and surprisingly challenging) question, and I'm not sure what the best solution is, but I went ahead and created a few macros for various options, just to see what various possibilities might look like.

Independent of whatever solution is used, one thing I would recommend is to insert a very tiny amount of horizontal space after the `\TeX`, just to ensure that the X doesn't run into the S visually. A hair-space is too wide, but `\hspace{.03em}` seems to do the trick.

Here is what I came up with. First a picture:

[image]

My favorite for regular use is (1), and for small-caps use my favorite is (2a)—although (3b) doesn't look too bad to me as long as there is a slight amount of space between the X and the S.

And now the LaTeX code. I started with Hendrik's kerning of `\TeX` in small caps, wrapped it into a `\scTeX` control sequence, and built up options from there:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

% \TeX in small caps
\newcommand\scTeX{%
  \textsc{t\kern -.12em\lower.4ex\hbox{e}\kern-.1em x}%
}

% 1. TeXShop natural with \TeX with regular "Shop"
\newcommand\TeXShop{%
  \hbox{\TeX\hspace{.03em}Shop}%
}

% 2a. TeXShop with uppercase \TeX with small caps "Shop"
\newcommand\TeXscShop{%
  \hbox{\TeX\hspace{.03em}\textsc{Shop}}%
}

% 2b. TeXShop with uppercase \TeX with small caps "shop"
\newcommand\TeXscshop{%
  \hbox{\TeX\hspace{.03em}\textsc{shop}}%
}

% 3a. TeXShop with small caps \TeX with small caps "Shop"
\newcommand\scTeXscShop{%
  \hbox{\scTeX\hspace{.03em}\textsc{Shop}}%
}

% 3b. TeXShop with small caps \TeX with small caps "shop"
\newcommand\scTeXscshop{%
  \hbox{\scTeX\hspace{.03em}\textsc{shop}}%
}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
%\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
%\cmidrule(r){1-2}
%& Appearance & Description \\
%\midrule
(0) & TeXShop & unadorned\\[2pt]
(1) & \TeXShop & natural\\[8pt]
(2a) & \TeXscShop & regular ``\TeX'' with small caps ``Shop''\\[2pt]
(2b) & \TeXscshop & regular ``\TeX'' with small caps ``shop''\\[8pt]
(3a) & \scTeXscShop & small caps ``\TeX'' with small caps ``Shop''\\[2pt]
(3b) & \scTeXscshop & small caps ``\TeX'' with small caps ``shop''\\[2pt]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

*Note: this code only works for regular 10pt roman text. It fails quite poorly for italics, slant, and boldface.*

What did you end up doing for a small-caps version of `\LaTeX`?

Answer (score 0):

What if you completely ignore the `\texsc` for this, and just do `\scalebox{0.8}{\TeX SHOP}`?

Comment: Then you won't be using small caps, but instead smaller capital letters! In a well-designed font the two cases are different.